# what is the green dot that appears in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

In android development there is an icon of directory with a green dot on it.

I don't understand what is this icon used for...

In one place I have read that it means "android module",

but I know that "androidTest" and "main" are not modules, but still they have got this icon.

I am really confused and hope that you guys can help clarify it to me...

[image]

and generally, the module icon should be gray directory with blue rectangle.

in practice, it is a blank folder, and other directories such as "test[unit]" got the module icon.

why is that really?

Answer (score 1):

That means that the module in question is "live/active". This normally refers to portions of your project that have an active "Run configuration". Most of those configurations are created automatically, when AS detects a specific type of module (tests/build variants/etc.)

For example, if you have multiple build variants, and have specific folders for those build variants, try changing the active build variant for a specific module and notice that the "green dor" will change to the build variant that is active at that moment.
[image]
[image]

Comment: yes but shouldn't a module have its own icon? without the green dot it is just a blank directory @miguelarc

Comment: That also depends in the way in which you are viewing your project in AS. In the top left of your "Project" tab, you have multiple viewing modes (Project/Packages/Project Files/...). If you select the "Project" viewing mode, AS will show you the project structure in the same way as you will see it if you open your project in the File Explorer. However, if you open it up in "Android" viewing mode, you'll see different icons for some of the folders, which are packages.

Comment: As default, when you create an AS mobile project, a "mobile" module will be created, and if you have a "Run configuration" active for that module, you'll see that the "mobile" module will have that green icon. Same as for test modules, if you have test configurations active for that.

Comment: just one more unclear thing: generally, the module icon should be gray directory with blue rectangle.

in practice, it is a blank folder, and other directories such as "test[unit]" got the module icon.

why is that really?

Comment: It can also depend in the way in which the module was added to your project. Some modules are created by you, while others could be imported by you (importing a .aar file to your project "libs" folder).

Comment: but like just to clerify, why is the test[unit] has the module icon? even though it is not a module

Comment: Most likely because it also has executable code, for example, unit or instrumented tests. If you go there you should have an example of a test, and there should be a "run" icon right next to it. If you click on it, it creates a new run configuration up top (as it does when you run your app module.